# How to override a react modal with another

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a session expiration modal in react that that lets a user know that their session is about to be over.  I'm using Auth0 to get the expires_in value and using setTimeout to determine when this module should show on pages.  My problem is that on some of the pages, I have modals that are brought up when the user is editing.  I'd like session expiration modal to override the edit modals so that only 1 modal is showing up at a time.

I originally had that code written for the session expiration modal like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { entry, isExpired } = this.props;
    entry();
    this.timerHandle = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ show: true });
      this.timerHandle = 0;
    }, isExpired);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.timerHandle) {
      clearTimeout(this.timerHandle);
      this.timerHandle = 0;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      logout,
    } = this.props;
    if (this.state.show) {
      return (
        <SkyLightStateless
          isVisible={this.state.show}
          hideOnOverlayClicked
          dialogStyles={{
            width: '300px'
          }}
```

However, I'm trying to figure out how to handle the other modal so that I know to hide it when this one is showing.  But, all the examples I've seen rely on some sort of handling the change through a user action, for example:

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.onChange}>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your problem very well, but why don't you fire some action inside your `setTimeout`? Something like `hideAllModals` which forces all modals to be hidden?

Comment: Thanks!  I was thinking I could use setState and share the state with the other modals to know when it was open.  But, it is such an edge case that I think using the dialogStyes from SkyLightStateless (the zIndex) may be fine here to provide some sort of override.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend overthinking your tiniest bits of code, especially when you're on a tight time schedule, but you should always ask yourself when creating new components, in what other cases could you need this component again? And how hard would it be modify your component again to match that case.
This isn't an optional lesson when learning react, sooner or later you'll have to rewrite a lot of code to understand how often you will need your component to be a bit more generic.